# IOS/SWIFT Push notification with Rpush gem: Invalid token (8) on production

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, heroku, swift3

Well I'm actually adding push notification to my project that I do with ruby on rails and Rpush. My problem is that on local all is working fine but on my production server that is on Heroku I get this error `Notification 7 failed with error: Invalid token (8)`.

I follow this step to generate my certificate on Apple: [developer apple certificate](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/create/)
And this step to get my pem file on Rpush Github: [github.com/rpush](https://github.com/rpush/rpush/wiki/Generating-Certificates)

And this is my code for the push notification on ios devices:

```
def push_notif_ios(user, ss)
  if !Rpush::Apns::App.find_by_name("ios-appName_#{Rails.env}")
    app = Rpush::Apns::App.new
    app.name = "ios-appName_#{Rails.env}"
    app.certificate = File.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'app/assets/config', "#{Rails.env}.pem"))
    app.environment = "#{Rails.env}" # APNs environment.
    app.password = "appPassword_#{Rails.env}"
    app.connections = 1
    app.save!
  end
  n = Rpush::Apns::Notification.new
  n.app = Rpush::Apns::App.find_by_name("ios-appName_#{Rails.env}")
  n.device_token = ss.supplier.user.device_code # 64-character hex string
  n.alert = "Nueva solicitud de appName de: #{user.name}, por el servicio de: #{ss.service.name}"
  # n.data = { foo: :bar }
  n.save!
end
```

Here I'm sure to get a correct device_token that obtain from a specific device because it's working on development.

Someone could help me to fix this problem ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it can help other people but that the way that I solved it:

1. `heroku pg:reset`
2. `heroku run rake db:migrate`
3. `heroku run rake db:seed`

And know is sending the push notification successfully !